# Building MVC 2 Areas into separate assemblies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to have the areas as part of the MVC project but to be built into their own individual assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible: you just have to embed the aspx/ascx as resource and you can use it this way.

But for maintainance reasons I rather would not recommend it.

Comment: I don't want the views to be in the assembly, just compiled code. It is so that I can have separate DLL's for each area which makes it easier to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the [portable areas](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx) feature of [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/). There has been [some discussion on the mvcvontrib mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/mvccontrib-discuss/browse_thread/thread/aeb5fd24e498e0cf/8c20105d10eac565#8c20105d10eac565) in the last few days about the sample app that apparently was not working. I haven't checked whether that is now fixed or not, but I think this will point you in the right direction.